# obtain the value of the OPTION TAG html

Tags: javascript, html

im want to obtain, the value of `<option value="somevalue">this value i want</option>`obviusly i had done to get the real value, but i want to show that value. for example `<option value="1">red color</option>` how ... to get "red color"  and put in a variable or anyelse HTML Tag. thanks

Comment: And you didn't try anything before asking this...?

Comment: sorry ... im not sure ... how to determine my statement on Google(to get that).... that downvotes. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess similar solutions are found a lot, here is mine:

```
<select onchange="showSelection(this)">
  <option>Select</option>
  <option value="blue">Roses are blue</option>
  <option value="red">Roses are red</option>
</select>
<script>
function showSelection(e) {
  alert( e.options[ e.selectedIndex ].innerHTML );
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Either the same way as you would get the text from any other element (read the `innerHTML` or find the textNode in the DOM and read its `data`) or via the `text` property of the HTMLOptionElementNode.

Answer (score 0):

```
    // Basically, you can do this:

        <select id="test">
          <option value="1">red color</option>
        </select>

   // JS:


        var e = document.getElementById("test");
                var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
```

This is correct and should give you the value. Is it the text you're after?

```
        var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;



This option has:

Index = 0
Value = 1
Text = red text
```